# Something is blocking access to variables and imports in the global scope of JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am writing a Chrome browser extension and have the following code:

```
import { takeScreenshot } from './screenshot.js';
const solveBtn = document.getElementById('solveBtn');
solveBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true}, (tabs) => {
        const tab = tabs[0];
        if (tab) {
            chrome.scripting.executeScript({
                target: {tabId: tab.id, allFrames: false},
                func: findCaptch
            }, onResult)
        }
        else throw new Error('There are no active tabs')
    })
})
let testVariable = 1
const findCaptch = async () => {
    const widgetFrame = document.querySelector('iframe[src*="google.com/recaptcha"]');
    const widgetDocument = widgetFrame.contentDocument ||         widgetFrame.contentWindow.document;
    const checkbox = widgetDocument.querySelector('.recaptcha-checkbox');
    

    checkbox.click()
    console.log(testVariable) //code stops working

    
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(testVariable) Uncaught ReferenceError: testVariable is not defined 
        ...some code...

       }
```

However, when I try to use something declared in the global scope inside the function findCaptch, my code stops without errors in the console. And if I use the same variables inside setTimeout(), the console throws an error 'Uncaught ReferenceError: testVariable is not defined'. What could be causing this issue?

I tried to use these variables outside the global scope, inside setTimeout, because I really need them, but now I need to use import and I can't do that because the function is still undefined inside setTimeout.

Comment: Anything declared/imported inside a module is not global, it's in the namespace of the wrapping module. A script with type of module (`<script type="module">`) is a module too, and it has its own namespace, which is not accessible from outside, like from the global namespace.

Comment: "and have the following code" - Where do you have the code? Background script, content script, popup?

Comment: Thomas Mueller, my code is attached to popup document

Answer (score 1):

**Functions injected by `executeScript` cannot reference the original outer scope** (variables, functions, modules, etc.) because the function itself doesn't run at all, only its source code is transferred into the target page as a string and evaluated in the target page as an IIFE like `(${functionSourceCode})(${args})`.

To change the behavior of the injected code:

- inject different functions
- specify `args`, [example](/a/68640372)
- [send messages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging)